# Raspberry Yocto image boot stops at crnod : OK

Tags: pi-4, boot, yocto

I've built a Yocto linux image for Raspberry4. the boot starts normally, but after reaching `crond : Ok`, nothing happens. it stuck there

I used `bitbake core-image-full-cmdline` to build the image

[image]